# How can I link a comment to its corresponding post in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django project where I have an index page that lists all posts. The user can click on the name of a post and this will take them to a detail page with the complete post information (date, content, category). This detail page also has a link that will take the user to a form where they can leave a comment. Once the user clicks submit they are supposed to navigate back to the post detail page and the comment is supposed to be there. The issue I am having right now is that the comment is being automatically assigned to the first post in the index list rather than the post the user had visited (I think this may have something to do with the current default setting in my models, but how else can I get the post id?). How can I make it so that the comment is assigned to its correct post? I have tried everything with the models and views but nothing seems to work. Thank you for your help, I think the solution to this might be simple but I can't find it anywhere.

Here is my relevant models:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1,
                        on_delete = models.CASCADE
                        )
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the UserPost object."""
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this user post."""
        return reverse('userpost-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1,
                        on_delete = models.CASCADE
                        )
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def comment_default():
        return {UserPost.id}
    
    post = models.ForeignKey(UserPost, default= comment_default, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the comment object."""
        return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.author, self.created_on)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('userpost-detail', args=[str(self.post.id)])
```

And my views:

```
class UserPostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = UserPost
    #post = UserPost.objects.get(id=id)
    #comments = Comment.objects.filter(Comment.post)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Comment'] = UserPost.comments
        return context


 
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = UserPost
    fields = ['title', 'category', 'content']

class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['post','content']
```

And my html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}
<h1>Title: {{ userpost.title }}</h1>
  <p><strong>Author:</strong> {{ userpost.author }}</p> 
  <p><strong>Content:</strong> {{ userpost.content }}</p>
  <p><strong>Category:</strong> {{ userpost.category }}</p>

  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'comment-create' %}" role="button">Leave a Comment</a>

  <h3>Comments:</h3>
    {% for comment in userpost.comments.all %}
    <p>
        On {{comment.created_on.date }}&nbsp;
        <b>{{ comment.author }}</b> wrote:
    </p>
    <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass Post ID in your url for this.

```
path("comment/<int:post_id>/", CommentCreateView, name="comment-create")
```

Now in template

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'comment-create' userpost.id %}" role="button">Leave a Comment</a>
```

Views

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content'] # remove field post here 

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs.get("post_id")
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!!